# Geographical location of Gan Eden

Tags: sources-mekorot, genesis-bereishith, adam, gan-eden

Do the sources give us the location of Gan Eden in which Adam and Chava lived?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.19a.20?lang=bi&with=all

Comment: As the Torah says, it was in Eden, so perhaps, in the name of pedantry, the question should be where is Eden

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30452/27180